# C#. Binding object to object

Tags: c#, data-binding

I develop the part of app functionality. I have the databinding object 'A' and another object 'B'.

```
public class SomeProxy
{       
    public SomeProxy(BindingSource A)
    {          
        var b = new B(A.SomeProperty);          
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B(List<T> somePropertyFromA)
    {
        SomePropertyFromA = somePropertyFromA;
    }

    public int SomePropertyFromA{get;set;}

    //Some autocalculated propeties, that are based on SomePropertyFromA

    //I want to reculculate them, when the SomePropertyFromA will be changed
}
```

'B' object culculates some values, based on the property 'a' of the 'A' object. 
I want to bind property in object 'B' to the same property 'a' in 'A'. It's need to handle on changes of the 'a' property, because some UI controls are binded to 'B'-s properties.
How can I do this?

Sorry for some oddness. Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear. How are you doing the binding? What is the "databinding object"? It would help if you posted some code.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to ask this question more clear..

Comment: If you are binding objects together.  Check out Automapper (http://automapper.codeplex.com/Wikipage)  It has support for binding properties of one object to methods or a method of your choosing based on data from the other object.  so a.GetTotal() can be set to b.Total and much more complicated scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you need a bi-directional link?

Both A and B can have properties that point to each other. Just be sure to create object B -outside- of A, so that you can do dependency injection.
Order of things should be:

```
B objectB = new B();
A objectA = new A(objectB);
```

Basic rule: do not create objects in constructors.

Comment: Yeap.. I understanded that I can't to specify this question completely clear.